# Pandas Time series: Efficient operation on daily data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

Generating the data

```
random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(date_rng), 3)),
                  columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                  index= date_rng)
daily_mean_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([len(date_rng), 3]),
                             columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                             index= date_rng)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], df.shape, p=[.35, .65]).astype(bool)
df[mask] = np.nan

# Data column to calculate each day
day = [['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data3'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data3']]
```

I want to select data by each day, and for each day I will calculate mean based on some columns (different for each day), given by the `day` variable.

Expected outcome:

```
                     mean
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00   5.0
2018-01-01 02:00:00   2.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00   6.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00   5.5
...                   ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00   4.0
2018-01-07 21:00:00   7.0
2018-01-07 22:00:00   5.0
2018-01-07 23:00:00   NaN
2018-01-08 00:00:00   2.0
```

I know I can loop through the day and calculate by:

```
i = 0
b = 0
for day_ in np.unique(test.index.date):
    a = test[test.index.date == day_]
    print(day_)
    print(b, len(a))

    daily_mean_df.iloc[b:b+len(a), 0] = np.mean(a[~np.isnan(a[day[i]])], axis = 1)
    i += 1
    b += len(a)
```

However for large dataset, this method will take very long time.
Please suggest me efficient way to calculate in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create boolean mask with same index like first `DataFrame` with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `max` per rows and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'`:

```
day = [['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data3'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data2'],
       ['data2', 'data3'],
       ['data1', 'data3']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(day, index=df.index.floor('d').unique())
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='', dtype=bool).max(axis=1, level=0)
df1 = df1.reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
print (df1.head())
                     data1  data2  data3
2018-01-01 00:00:00   True   True  False
2018-01-01 01:00:00   True   True  False
2018-01-01 02:00:00   True   True  False
2018-01-01 03:00:00   True   True  False
2018-01-01 04:00:00   True   True  False
```

So you can replace non matched values to `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and calculate `mean`:

```
df = df.where(df1).mean(axis=1).to_frame('mean')
print (df)
                     mean
2018-01-01 00:00:00   6.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00   NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00   4.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00   4.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00   4.5
                  ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00   NaN
2018-01-07 21:00:00   6.0
2018-01-07 22:00:00   5.0
2018-01-07 23:00:00   3.0
2018-01-08 00:00:00   5.0

[169 rows x 1 columns]
```

**Setup**:

```
np.random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(date_rng), 3)),
                  columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                 index= date_rng)
daily_mean_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([len(date_rng), 1]),
                             columns=['data1'],
                             index= date_rng)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], df.shape, p=[.35, .65]).astype(bool)
df[mask] = np.nan
```

Verifying solution:

```
i = 0
b = 0
for day_ in np.unique(df.index.date):
    a = df[df.index.date == day_]
#    print(day_)
#    print(b, len(a))

    daily_mean_df.iloc[b:b+len(a), 0] = np.mean(a[~np.isnan(a[day[i]])], axis = 1)
    i += 1
    b += len(a)

print (daily_mean_df)
                     data1
2018-01-01 00:00:00    6.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00    NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00    4.5
                   ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00    NaN
2018-01-07 21:00:00    6.0
2018-01-07 22:00:00    5.0
2018-01-07 23:00:00    3.0
2018-01-08 00:00:00    5.0

[169 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the day from a datetime index like this:

```
df["day"] = df.index.floor('D')
```

And then group by this new column and compute the average per group with:

```
df.groupby("day").mean()
```

Result:

```
               data1     data2      data3
day             
2018-01-01  4.428571    3.714286    5.454545
2018-01-02  5.066667    5.444444    5.222222
2018-01-03  4.850000    3.705882    4.812500
2018-01-04  4.555556    4.818182    3.764706
2018-01-05  4.000000    4.058824    3.818182
2018-01-06  6.058824    4.588235    4.866667
2018-01-07  4.176471    4.071429    5.055556
2018-01-08  4.400000    4.400000    4.285714
```

Note that, by default pandas.mean skip NaN values, but that can be changed with the [skipna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) parameter.

Comment: I mean that I want to select all the data per day, and calculate mean of each hour by the selected column of that day, not by grouping all data of the day together.

I just added the expected outcome to be clearer